# angularjs parse json with "\"

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, parsing

I have the following json (which exists in $scope.projectData).

```
[{
   "\"Space\"": "\"L1 (1 floor)\"",
   "\"Subject\"": "\"Corridor Distance\"",
   "\"Label\"": "\"Corridor Distance\"",
   "\"Color\"": "\"#33CCCC\"",
   "\"Length\"": "\"193.55\"",
   "\"Count\"": "\"0\"",
   "\"Multiplier\"": "\"1\"",
   "\"TotalFt\"": "\"193.55\"",
   "\"TotalCounts\"": "\"\"",
   "\"Notes\"": "\"\""},
{
   "\"Space\"": "\"L1 (1 floor)\"",
   "\"Subject\"": "\"Corridor Distance\"",
   "\"Label\"": "\"Corridor Distance\"",
   "\"Color\"": "\"#33CCCC\"",
   "\"Length\"": "\"210.36\"",
   "\"Count\"": "\"0\"",
   "\"Multiplier\"": "\"1\"",
   "\"TotalFt\"": "\"210.36\"",
   "\"TotalCounts\"": "\"\"",
   "\"Notes\"": "\"\"" }]
```

this is my controller

```
$scope.csvParse = function(item) {

    var array = JSON.parse(item);
     console.log(item);

  };
```

and my html

```
{{ csvParse(projectData) }}
```

my code is not working.  any suggestions?

Comment: You need to double the escape char for javascript `JSON.parse('[{   "\\"Space\\"": "\\"L1 (1 floor)\\""}]');`

Comment: `csvParse` have no return value.

Comment: do i need a regexp? what would that be?

Comment: That is some really whack JSON. What is generating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do the following?

```
 $scope.projectData = [{
   "Space": "L1 (1 floor)",
   "Subject": "Corridor Distance",
   "Label": "Corridor Distance",
   "Color": "#33CCCC",
   "Length": "193.55",
   "Count": "0",
   "Multiplier": "1",
   "TotalFt": "193.55",
   "TotalCounts": "",
   "Notes": ""},
{
   "Space": "L1 (1 floor)",
   "Subject": "Corridor Distance",
   "Label": "Corridor Distance",
   "Color": "#33CCCC",
   "Length": "210.36",
   "Count": "0",
   "Multiplier": "1",
   "TotalFt": "210.36",
   "TotalCounts": "",
   "Notes": "" }];
```

and

```
{{ projectData }}
```

EDIT: Alternatively, you can fix your projectData by changing your csvParse as follows:

```
function clean(str) {
  return str.replace(/\"/g, "")
}

$scope.csvParse = function(objs) {
  var newObjs = [];

  objs.forEach(function(obj) {
    var newObj = {};

    for(var key in obj) {
      val = obj[key];

      newObj[clean(key)] = clean(val);
    }

    newObjs.push(newObj);
  });

  return newObjs;
};
```

Comment: I don't have control over how data comes.  I need to "fix" what I have in order to use them